# How can I detect a mouse click using an Edge Collider 2D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Using the function

```
    void OnMouseDown() {
    // Do code
    }
```

I can check if my object's box collider is clicked. When I switch the collider to be an edge collider it no longer detects any mouse clicks.

Is it impossible to use OnMouseDown() for Edge Colliders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`OnMouseDown` only works if your EdgeCollider has an  Edge Radius that is greater than 0. If your Collider is infinitely thin, you can't really hit it with your mouse